# How does the new ASP.NET 5 pipeline integrate with the current IIS pipeline?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, iis-8.5

I am hosting all of my projects on IIS-Webservers and I will not change that.

I would like to understand how the new ASP.NET 5 middleware modules work together with existing IIS Modules. One example: If I write my Authentication module as an ASP.NET 5 middleware module, will IIS and the IIS modules recognize at authorization that the user was authenticated in an ASP.NET 5 middleware module?

In which order are all of the modules (IIS and middleware) executed? It is not clear for me, how deep the integration in IIS is. When will an ASP.NET 5 middleware module run in relation to the Lifecycle Events of the IIS Integrated pipeline? I found a `IntegratedPipelineExtensions.UseStageMarker()` method which indicates to me that there is some Integration with the IIS Integrated pipeline. Will the IIS lifecycle Events be raised, within the chain of middleware modules, so that all Modules (IIS and Middleware) are executed in some mixed order?

Also, what is the benefit of using middleware modules over IIS modules for the same functionality? For example delivering static files can be done with both?

Comment: About your last question: If you plan to deploy on `IIS` you don't need to load `StaticFile middleware` in your `Startup.cs`. You can make a conf by environment in your startup class.

Comment: The problem with discouraging the StaticFile call is that in the event IIS is no longer used the line will need to be added in, there is no harm in it being there so it might as well be left in.

Comment: FYI `IntegratedPipelineExtensions.UseStageMarker()` is part of the Owin/Katana project, not part of ASP.NET 5.